# Share a file to another user on Linux

Tags: linux, file

I have (unmodifiable) server processes running on different tcp ports as different users. Scripts running as nonprivileged users need to pass filepaths (readable to them) to the server processes. The filepaths are likely to be unaccessible by the server processes. The scripts could copy each filepath to a shared location (`/tmp/something/`) and pass the shared filepath instead. Can I achieve the same effect without copying files? Hardlinking may not be feasible as filepaths will likely be on a different filesystem than the one `/tmp/something/` is on.

Comment: Usually such conditions are matched with file permissions directly. Can't you introduce a shared user group and force suitable permissions by means of setting a umask in the shell skeleton?

Comment: This is basically to allow parallel batch processing with `libreoffice`.  Libreoffice headless servers don't allow multiple servers per user. Starting each `libreoffice` server as a different user solves this, however there's the sharing issue if I wanted to publish this as an installable solution (I can't dictate people what they `umask` should be). Right now, I can't think of anything other than making the user script setuid root.

Comment: And what about storing those documents on a special filesystem so that you can remote control file ownership/permissions by means of the mount configuration?

Comment: Isn't that essentially the same as copying to `/tmp`? Those docs to be batch processed won't be mine. They'll belong to the user of the script.

Comment: I'd say that is something completely different... First: you do not copy, thus you save time, space, redundancy and cleanup effort. Second: you con't have to do anything on the client side. The only required precondition is that files are always saved on that mounted file system. This is typically done for classical "document" resources.

Comment: Looks good and might solve the problem. I'll look into it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

To share it within same group:

```
chmod g+rw myfile.txt
```

To share it with other users:

```
chmod o+rw myfile.txt
```

Comment: This won't help very much if `myfile.txt` is in a directory that other users can't `cd` into.

Comment: Agreed. But question says about file so i am assuming directory has permission while the file doesn't.